# Oracle Add Date Column to Existing Table (default to sysdate new rows only)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Is there a way to add column DATE_CREATED such as only new rows will pickup the default sysdate?  When I ran the ALTER below, all priors rows got the DATE_CREATED set to the run-time of the ALTER script; I would prefer them to remain null.

```
alter table abc.mytable
  add 
    (DATE_CREATED        date   default sysdate null
    );
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to first add the column without a default:

```
alter table mytable add date_created date default null;
```

and then add define the default value:

```
alter table mytable modify date_created default sysdate;
```